# How to display <figure> images on same line HTML/CSS

Tags: inline, figure

I have 4 images within  elements with captions within  elements.

Each image is displayed under each other like:

IMAGE
*caption*

IMAGE
*caption*

IMAGE
*caption*

IMAGE
*caption*

I would like the images to appear like:

IMAGE IMAGE  IMAGE  IMAGE
*caption* *caption* *caption* *caption*

My HTML:

```
<div id="earlylife_images">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/early/moore01.jpg" alt="Roger Moore Teenage" width="150" height="150">
                <figcaption>A young Roger Moore</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure>
                <img src="images/early/moore02.jpg" alt="Roger Moore 30's" width="150" height="150">
                <figcaption>Roger Moore in his 30's</figcaption>                    
            </figure>

            <figure>
                <img src="images/early/moore03.jpg" alt="Roger Moore as James Bond" width="150" height="150">
                <figcaption>Roger Moore as James Bond</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure>
                <img src="images/early/moore04.jpg" alt="Roger Moore Recent" width="150" height="150">
                <figcaption>Roger Moore in more recent years</figcaption>               
            </figure>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was thinking about:

```
figure {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cBkTc/3/

Comment: Thank you very much! Works a treat

Answer (score 20):

Make `figure` `inline-block`.

```
figure { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `div` and add `figure` inside it (make `figure` `inline-block`)

HTML

```
<div>
   <figure>
      <img src="">
      <figcaption>1</figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
      <img src="">
      <figcaption>2</figcaption>
   </figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```